# Recording webcam with flash media server

Tags: flash, video, webcam, flash-media-server, video-recording

I'm trying to make a web app that lets the user record a video message. I'm trying to get the best quality possible (even if it means long upload times).
I manage to get recording working with `ns.publish("livestream", "live");` 
The server code looks like this:

```
Client.prototype.startRecord = function( source, destination ) {
        trace("recording Stream: " + source + " to: " + destination);
        this.newStream = Stream.get(destination);
        this.fileRecording = destination;
        trace(this.fileRecording);

        if (this.newStream)
        {
            this.newStream.onStatus = function (info) {
                //trace(info.code );
                if (info.code == "NetStream.Play.PublishNotify") {              
                    trace("start recording");
                    this.record();
                }   
            }

            this.newStream.play(source)

        }
    }

    Client.prototype.stopRecord = function() {
        trace("stopping Recording");
        this.newStream.record(false);
        this.newStream.play(false);
    }

    Client.prototype.getFiles = function() {
        var fileRecord = new File("/streams/_definst_/"+this.fileRecording+".flv");

        if (fileRecord.exists)
        {
            return this.fileRecording;
        }

        return "error recording";
    }


    application.onConnect = function(clObj) {
        this.acceptConnection(clObj);
    }
```

The problem is that the quality is not great. I tried using `ns.publish("livestream", "record");` , but its making 2 files on the server and quality doesn't improve, any suggestion? I can also upload the client code if you need it.

Client code:

```
import flash.media.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.net.*;
import flash.utils.getTimer;

var vid:Video;
var mic:Microphone;
var cam:Camera;
var fileListObj:Object = {};
var ns:NetStream;
var nc:NetConnection;
var recordingName:String;

initCamera();

function initCamera ():void
{
    if (Camera.isSupported)
    {
        cam = Camera.getCamera();

        cam.setMode (800, 480, 24);
        //cam.setQuality(0, 90);
        vid = new Video(cam.width,cam.height);

        vid.attachCamera (cam);

        if (Microphone.isSupported)
        {
            mic = Microphone.getEnhancedMicrophone();       
        }

        this.addChildAt (vid, 1);

        vid.x = (800 - vid.width) >> 1;
        vid.y = (480 - vid.height) >> 1;        

        initConnection();
    }
    else
    {
        trace ("no camera");
    }
}


function initConnection ():void
{
    nc = new NetConnection();

    nc.addEventListener (NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler);
    nc.addEventListener (AsyncErrorEvent.ASYNC_ERROR, function (event:AsyncErrorEvent):void {trace("error");});

    nc.connect ("rtmp://adrian7.srfms.com/nabCapture");
}



function recordVideo (event:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (record_mc.label == "Record")
    {
        record_mc.label = "Stop Record";

        var currentTime:Date = new Date();

        recordingName = "myRecording"+getTimer()+""+currentTime.time;

        nc.call ("startRecord", new Responder(startPublish), "livestream", recordingName);


    }
    else
    {
        record_mc.enabled = false;
        record_mc.label = "Record";

        nc.call ("stopRecord", null);
        ns.close();

        nc.call ("getFiles", new Responder(onResultFileListObj, null));     
    }
}

function startPublish (result:Object):void
{
    ns.publish("livestream", "live");
}

function netStatusHandler (event:NetStatusEvent):void
{
    //trace (event.info.code);
    if (event.info.code == "NetConnection.Connect.Success")
    {
        ns = new NetStream(nc);

        ns.attachCamera (cam);
        if (mic)
        {
            ns.attachAudio(mic);
        }

        record_mc.enabled = true;
        record_mc.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, recordVideo);
    }
}



function onResultFileListObj (resultObj:Object):void 
{
    if (String(resultObj) != "error recording")
    {
        recordingName = String(resultObj);

        see_mc.enabled = true;
        see_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function (event:MouseEvent):void {
                        navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.labs.adrian281990.com/fms_demo1/index.php?id=" + recordingName), "_self");
                                });
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, show the client code. The client can configure the webcam's capture resolution with [Camera.setMode()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Camera.html#setMode()) and set some a preference for picture quality or bandwidth consumption with [Camera.setQuality()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Camera.html#setQuality())

Comment: cam = Camera.getCamera();
 
  cam.setMode (800, 480, 24);
  //cam.setQuality(0, 90);
  vid = new Video(cam.width,cam.height);
 
  vid.attachCamera (cam);
 
  if (Microphone.isSupported)
  {
   mic = Microphone.getEnhancedMicrophone();  
  }

Comment: Videos (and the resolutions that web cameras support) are usually in a 4:3 ratio. The web cam probably does not support 800x480, so Flash tries to find something close. The result may not be so good. Try using different values: 800x600, 640x480, 480x360 or some other values w/a 4:3 ratio. If the end result needs to be some other size you can scale or crop the video (w/some effort). I get great results at 480x360.

Answer (score 0):

### Use a common resolution and avoid the default setQuality values

You should start by making the following to changes:

1. Use a common resolution like 640x480 and a frame rate of 30
2. Avoid the default `cam.setQuality` settings and use `cam.setQuality(0,90)`

the above translates in the following client AS3 code:

```
cam.setMode (640, 480, 24);
cam.setQuality(0, 90);
```

**`cam.setMode(640,480,24);`**

What happens is that you're currently requesting 800x480@24fps from the webcam. 800x480@24fps is not a widely supported resolution which means on most webcams you'll get whatever the webcam responds with (which might not be the best quality).  Requesting a *common* resolution like 640 x 480 @ 30fps will ensure you're getting just that on most webcams.

**`cam.setQuality(0, 90);`**

Your `cam.setQuality` is commented which means it will use the default values which translates into: vary the picture quality to keep the bitrate under 130kbits/s ( or 16384bytes/second).

130kbits/s is VERY LOW. Use `cam.setQuality(0, 90)` to tell Flash to use as much bandwidth as needed to keep the picture quality at 90.

See [Camera.SetQuality](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000880.html) documentation for more info.

### Red5 version

If you're using Red5, you should make sure you're using at least [Red5 1.0.3](https://github.com/Red5/red5-server). It's the 1st version with video recording fixed. All previous versions had video recording broken, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18799148/recording-high-quality-video-using-flash-and-red5-media-server) for details.

### Commercial solutions

You should also consider using a commercial solution like [HDFVR](https://hdfvr.com/) or [Pipe](https://addpipe.com/) which handle everything including mobile and the conversion to .mp4 .

### Regarding your "2 files" observation

> but its making 2 files on the server and quality doesn't improve

Depending on the media server you're using you might get 1, 2 or more files.

[Red5](https://github.com/Red5/red5-server) for example will create 2 other files  during the recording process (.ser and .info):

[image]

and, after the 1st playback, it will create another .meta file which holds the list of keyframe, their byte position and timestamp:

[image]

Here's the contents of such a .meta file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FrameMetadata audioOnly="false" duration="24074" modified="1446217872000">
    <KeyFrame position="566" timestamp="39"/>
    <KeyFrame position="626" timestamp="40"/>
    <KeyFrame position="14705" timestamp="574"/>
    <KeyFrame position="14765" timestamp="575"/>
    ...
</FrameMetadata>
```